# Separate environments for learning or trying out vs production (sandboxes?)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, express, development-environment

Can you suggest me a way of separating learning/trying out vs production in the same computer? I am in such a place that I know a lot of JS and production ready skills whilst sometimes require probing or trying out simpler stuff or basics. I presume that a lot of engineers are also in a similar place.

This is the situation I am facing with right now.

- I wanted to install redis and configure it while trying out something interested.
- In a separate project I needed another clean redis configuration and installation.
- In front-end side I tried and installed a few npm packages globally.
- At some point I installed python 3.4 now require 3.6
- At some point I installed nginx and configured it, now need another configuration and wipe the previous one out,
- If I start a big project right now I feel like my computer will eventually let me down due to several attempts I previously done

et cetera, these all create friction on both my learning and exploration

Now, it crosses mind to use separate virtual box installations for trying out things, but this answer is trivial, please suggest something else.

P.S.: I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: Docker.  This is pretty much exactly what docker was invented for.

Comment: Thank you, I though Docker was only for containerizing your app with all the installation files and configurations before pushing to the production. But it never occurred to me that it can be used in that manner as well. Can you elaborate on a use case? How would you use it that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use Docker, which is also trivial,
however, if your environment is Linux you can use [LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction/)

Comment: Thank you, I also commented on this for @DanielFarrell but Docker seems plausible, can you suggest a use case scenario? I can't think of it outside of pushing a project to production.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a single good answer to this sort of question of course; but some things that are generally a good idea are:

1. use git repos to keep the source "backed up" (obviously your local pc should not be the git server); commit your changes all the time, if you can't hold your breath for as long as the timespan between 2 commits, then you're doing it wrong (or you may have asthma, see a doctor).
2. Always build your project with there being not just multiple, but a **variable amount** of "deployments" in mind. That means not hardcoding absolute paths and database names/ports/hostnames and things like that. If your project needs database/api credentials then that should be in a configfile of sorts (or in the env); that configfile should be stored outside the codebase and shouldn't be checked into your git repos (though there can ofcourse be a config template in there).
3. Always have at least 2 deployments of any project actually deployed. Next to the (obvious) "live"/"production" deployment, which your clients/users use, you want a "dev"-version for yourself where you can freely shit the bed, and for bigger projects you may well want multiple. Each deployment would have its own database, and it's own copy of the code/assets.
4. It can be useful to deploy everything inside podman or docker containers, that makes it easier to have a near-identical system in both development and production (incase those are different servers), but that may be too much overhead for you.
5. Have a method (maybe a script) that makes it very easy to deploy updates from your gitrepo or dev-deployment, to the production deployment. Based on your description, i'm guessing if a client tells you she wants some minor cosmetic changes done, you do them straight on the live version; very convenient and fast, but a horrible thing in practice. once you switch from that workflow to having a seperate dev-deploy, you'll feel slowed down by that (which you are), but if you optimize that workflow over time you'll get to the point where you could still deploy cosmetic changes in a minute orso, while having fully separated deployments, it is worth the time investment.
6. Have a personal devtools git repo or something similar. You're likely using an IDE such as VS code ? Back up your vs code user config in that repo, update it reasonably frequently. Use a texteditor, photoshop/editor, etc etc, same deal. You hear that ticking sound ? that's the bomb that's been placed on your motherboard. It might go off tonight, it might not go off for years, but you never know, always expect it could be today or tomorrow, so have stuff backed up externally and/or on offline media.

---

There's a lot more but those are some of the basics that spring to mind.

Comment: Raxi, thank you very much, it occurred to me that I can take a snapshot of my PC after installing my most comfortable tools and tweaking my dot files. Then preparing a complete installation batch file (including everything I like). So if my linux becomes clunky, at least I can come back and move on from there. My projects are always secured in separate hard disks, be it dev or production. No worries there. Also @RownumHighart suggested using docker and LCX, seems plausible as well. But your suggestions are about what comes after, I will consider them, too.

Comment: yea podman/docker is useful for that stuff; though if you're just starting out and working solo and the like, and your production server doesn't necessarily have a need for it; it may not entirely be worth the time investment right away

Comment: i would add btw, personally i think its useful to have a repo of your ide config and the like in a repo, separate from your regular system backup (which is ofc also a good idea to have; but thats not really dev-specific). reason is, if say you normally work from home behind your pc, you buy a laptop cause you want to work remotely or on holiday or w/e for a while; you likely dont want to mirror your entire life onto that machine; you could just download vscode and a bunch of tools and pull the conf from git. Same thing if you get a job somewhere and they expect you to work on their machines

Comment: + you can compare your current config against how it was 18 months ago, when you notice "hey im missing X, what did i fuck up last year?". If you're working in a narrow space (like only doing nodejs webdev) then perhaps that isn't super interesting, but personally i hop around a lot between many languages, many different dbms, etc. so its not uncommon to have to heavily work on a pl/pgsql project, after not having touched any of that for 2 years; meanwhile i'll have made 600 changes to my IDE (with other languages in mind) and all the pl/pgsql stuff broke.

Comment: Great comments, I checked Docker option and found a guy who did vscode configuration in it. But as you said, it would be a better idea to store the VS code config separately in a repo. What used to be a headache for me was my bipolar nature, switching constantly from python to node to python again (due to my different job requirements, I even used to use Matlab for back-end image processing). Nowadays I utilize JS more than anything. If I configure another use case for python, and push it to a repo, when I need a python dev environment I could just pull it and continue from there.

Comment: Yea "code environment" repo(s) are useful for that. The docker comment was really ment as seperate from the IDE/tools discussion though. That is more for your actual endproducts. You'd make an image which has say *bare-bones linux + git + nodejs + nginx/apache + redis/dbms/...* in it , pre-configured to your usecase (and so it starts those services on boot), pack in your webapp, use a "volume" for the configuration directory and other data that needs to survive server restarts.

Comment: that way when you have a new version you just update/download the new image (or even let it auto-update if you can be bothered to set all that up), then restart the pod/container and it'll run on with your latest stuff using the same databasefiles/config/etc the old container used. -- and if you ever end up having a need for some additional deploys, you just start another container from the same image, and it'll have its own db/redis/etc included, and its own config. Easy to tear stuff down that way.

Answer (score 0):

> I though Docker was only for containerizing your app with all the installation files and configurations before pushing to the production

Docker is useful whenever you need to configure the runtime environment in an isolated manner.  Production, local development, other environments - all need the same runtime.  All benefit from the runtime definition and isolation that docker provides.  Arguably docker is even *more* useful in workstation-centric development, than it is in production.

> I wanted to install redis and configure it while trying out something interested.

Instead of installing redis on your os directly, run [the preexisting docker image for redis](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis).

> In a separate project I needed another clean redis configuration and installation.

Instantiate the docker image again and now you have 2 isolated `redis` servers running locally.

> In front-end side I tried and installed a few npm packages globally.

Run your npm code within [a nodejs docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)

> At some point I installed python 3.4 now require 3.6

Different versions of [python is a great use case for docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), which will tagged with specific python versions.

> At some point I installed nginx and configured it, now need another configuration and wipe the previous one out,

[Nginx also has a very useful official container.](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)

> If I start a big project right now I feel like my computer will eventually let me down due to several attempts I previously done

Yeah, it gets messy quick.  That's why docker is such a great solution.  Give every project dedicated services and use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to simplify the networking and building components.   Fight the temptation to use a docker container for more than one service - instead stitch them together with docker networks.

Read https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/ to get started with docker.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are awesome. I now understand why I should use docker instead of might. Redis example was quite striking because I don't want to install a full-fledged mem-cache database on my desktop computer, such a thing is an abomination. I was guessing a docker like solution would exist, but not expecting the docker use case would actually cover it.